# Can sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer with strategy='quantile' drop the duplicated bins?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I used `sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=10, encode='ordinal')` to discretize my continuous feature.

The strategy is `'quantile'`, by defalut. But my data distribution is actually not uniformly, like 70% of rows is 0.

Then I got `KBinsDiscretizer.bins_edges=[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,256.,602., 1306., 18464.]`.

There're many duplicate bins. So, is there a method to drop the duplicates in KBinsDiscretizer's bins?

`KBinsDiscretizer` calculates the quantile of input. If the most samples of input are zero, the 10-quantiles will have multiple zeros. The result I expected is a discretizer with unique bins. For the example I mentioned, is `[0.,256.,602., 1306., 18464.]`.

Comment: What would you expect the function to do? What is your expected result?

Comment: In that case you should change your discretization strategy, maybe to 'uniform'?

Comment: Well, it seems that there is no other way. I will try 'uniform' stragegy. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it behaves well, i.e. the bins are not repeated:

```
sklearn.__version__
Out[18]: '1.3.0'

import sklearn.preprocessing
kbd = sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=10, encode='onehot')

kbd.fit(np.array([0]*10 + list(range(20)))[:, np.newaxis])
/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py:313: UserWarning: Bins whose width are too small (i.e., <= 1e-8) in feature 0 are removed. Consider decreasing the number of bins.
  warnings.warn(
Out[14]: KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=10)
kbd.bin_edges_
Out[15]: 
array([array([ 0. ,  1.6,  4.5,  7.4, 10.3, 13.2, 16.1, 19. ])],
      dtype=object)
kbd.fit(np.array([0]*100 + list(range(20)))[:, np.newaxis])
/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py:313: UserWarning: Bins whose width are too small (i.e., <= 1e-8) in feature 0 are removed. Consider decreasing the number of bins.
  warnings.warn(
Out[16]: KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=10)
kbd.bin_edges_
Out[17]: array([array([ 0. ,  7.1, 19. ])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

That will not be possible. Set `strategy='uniform'` to achieve your goal.